# Fields with the property $\Bbb{F}^\times / \{1, -1\}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\Bbb{F}^\times$.

Tags: field-theory, abelian-groups

The field of real numbers has the property that $\Bbb{R}^\times/\{1, -1\}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\Bbb{R}^\times$, namely the positive reals. This is because there is a homomorphism $f:\ \Bbb{R}^\times \to \Bbb{R}^\times$ given by $f(x) = |x|$.

I believe there evidence to believe that $\Bbb{F}_p$ has this property as well, since $\Bbb{F}_p^\times$ is a product of cyclic groups.

Not surprisingly, I find it hard to show that the complex numbers have this property.

How do I characterize all fields with this property?

Comment: All finite fields have this property because all abelian groups have the property that they have the same quotients and subgroups up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact $\Bbb{F}_p^{\times}$ is cyclic of order $p-1$, and hence any quotient of it is cyclic as well and its order divides $p-1$. Of course a cyclic group of order $p-1$ has a subgroup of any order dividing $p-1$, so every prime field $\Bbb{F}_p$ has this property. In fact the same argument shows that every finite field has this property.

---

In general, for any field $k$ the map
$$k^{\times}\ \longrightarrow\ k^{\times}:\ x\ \longmapsto\ x^2,$$
is a group homomorphism with kernel $\{1,-1\}$, so the quotient $k/\{1,-1\}$ is isomorphic to its image by the first isomorphism theorem, which is a subgroup of $k^{\times}$. This is the subgroup $k^{\times2}$ of squares in $k^{\times}$. In the particular case of $k=\Bbb{C}$ we see that $\Bbb{C}/\{1,-1\}\cong\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Okay, this isn't too surprisingly, but what about fields of characteristic 0? Like the complex numbers?

Comment: @abnry See my edit.

Comment: Great! One question tho: How do we know that the kernel of the square map is always $\{1, -1\}$? Couldn't there be elements in a field that have multiplicative order 2 that isn't -1?

Comment: A polynomial of degree $d$ with coefficients in a field $k$ has at most $d$ roots in that field $k$. Clearly $1$ and $-1$ are roots of $x^2-1=0$, and if $1=-1$ then $x^2-1=(x-1)^2$ so $1$ is a double root.