# Prove $F[x]/\langle p(cx)\rangle\cong F(\sqrt{b})$, and $F(\sqrt{a}) \cong F(\sqrt{b})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 27, Exercise F3.

> Let $F$ be a finite field. If $a, b \in F$, let $p(x) = x^2-a$ and $q(x) = x^2 - b$ be irreducible in $F[x]$,
>   and let $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ denote roots of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ in an extension of $F$.
>
> [Exercise F2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600649/why-a-b-is-a-square-and-sqrtb-is-a-root-of-pcx-in-a-finite-field) shows why $a/b$ is a square, say $a/b = c^2$ for some $c \in F$; and that $\sqrt{b}$
>   is a root of $p(cx)$.
>
> Prove that $F[x]/\langle p(cx)\rangle\cong F(\sqrt{b})$, and $F(\sqrt{a}) \cong F(\sqrt{b})$.

By [Exercise F2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600649/why-a-b-is-a-square-and-sqrtb-is-a-root-of-pcx-in-a-finite-field), $\sqrt{b}$ is a root of $p(cx)$, which implies $F[x]/\langle p(cx)\rangle\cong F(\sqrt{b})$.

By [Exercise E5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3605092/prove-fx-langle-pcx-rangle-cong-fx-langle-px-rangle), 
$F(\sqrt{a}) \cong F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle = F[x]/\langle p(cx)\rangle \cong F(\sqrt{b})$.

Correct?