# Prove that any two quadratic extensions of a finite field are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 27, Exercise F4.

> Use [Exercise F3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606616/prove-fx-langle-pcx-rangle-cong-f-sqrtb-and-f-sqrta-cong-f-sq) to prove: Any two quadratic extensions of a finite field are isomorphic.

Let $p(x) = x^2+\alpha x+\beta$ be an irreducible polynomial over a finite field $F$.
\begin{align*}
    p(x) &= x^2+\alpha x+\beta \\
    &= (x+\frac{\alpha}{2})^2 + (\beta-\frac{\alpha^2}{4})
\end{align*}

Let $\displaystyle y=x+\frac{\alpha}{2}, a = -(\beta-\frac{\alpha^2}{4})$, so
$\displaystyle p\left(y-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = y^2 - a$.
Let $\displaystyle \bar{p}(y) = p\left(y-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = y^2 - a$.

Note $a$ must be a non-square.  Suppose the opposite.  Let $a=c^2$ for some $c\in F$.
Then $\displaystyle\bar{p}(y)=p\left(y-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = y^2-c^2=(y+c)(y-c)\implies
p(x) = \left(x+\frac{\alpha}{2}+c\right)\left(x+\frac{\alpha}{2}-c\right)$, which contradicts that $p(x)$ is irreducible.

Let $\sqrt{a}$ denote the root of $\bar{p}(y)$.  In general, $F[x]/\langle p(x + k)\rangle \cong F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ for $k\in F$.  Hence, $F(\sqrt{a}) \cong F[y]/\langle \bar{p}(y)\rangle \cong F[y]/\langle p(y-\alpha/2)\rangle\cong F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$.

Similar argument can be made so that $F(\sqrt{b})\cong F[x]/\langle q(x)\rangle$ 
for a different irreducible quadratic polynomial $q(x)$ over $F$ such that $\bar{q}(y) = y^2 - b$.

By [Exercise F3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606616/prove-fx-langle-pcx-rangle-cong-f-sqrtb-and-f-sqrta-cong-f-sq), $F(\sqrt{a})\cong F(\sqrt{b})$, where $F(\sqrt{a})$ and $F(\sqrt{b})$ are any two quadratic extensions of a finite field $F$.

Does this look reasonable?

Comment: What about fields of even order?

Comment: This indeed does not work if $F$ has characteristic $2$. A possible attempt would be to consider the polynomial $X^{|F|^2}-X$