# Prove that any two simple extensions of $\Bbb{R}$ are isomorphic (hence isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 27, Exercise F5.

> If $a$ and $b$ are nonsquares in $\Bbb{R}, a/b$ is a square (why?).
>   Use the same argument as in [Exercise F4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607452/prove-that-any-two-quadratic-extensions-of-a-finite-field-are-isomorphic) to prove that any two simple extensions of $\Bbb{R}$ are isomorphic (hence isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$).

Obviously any positive real number is a square and any negative real number is a non-square in $\Bbb{R}$. If $a,b$ are non-squares in $\Bbb{R}$, $a/b$ must be positive and therefore a square.

Using the same argument in [Exercise F4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607452/prove-that-any-two-quadratic-extensions-of-a-finite-field-are-isomorphic), we can find an irreducible quadratic polynomial $p(x)$ over $\Bbb{R}$, such that $\bar{p}(y) = y^2 -a$. Let $\sqrt{a}$ denotes the root of $\bar{p}(y)$.
Then $\Bbb{R}(\sqrt{a})\cong\Bbb{R}[y]/\langle\bar{p}(y)\rangle$. Similarly, $\Bbb{R}(\sqrt{b})\cong\Bbb{R}[y]/\langle\bar{q}(y)\rangle$.

Using the same argument in [Exercise F3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606616/prove-fx-langle-pcx-rangle-cong-f-sqrtb-and-f-sqrta-cong-f-sq), $\Bbb{R}(\sqrt{a})\cong\Bbb{R}(\sqrt{b})$.
This implies any two simple extensions of $\Bbb{R}$ are isomorphic, and hence isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}(\sqrt{-1})=\Bbb{C}$.

Correct?